# How to compare numbers with 2 decimal places in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, numbers, compare, decimal

I'm trying to compare Office version numbers in vb.NET

How can I determine if: 12.0.64 is greater or less than say 12.0.62 or 14.0.4762

It seems the fact that there is 2 decimals, vb doesn't like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`Version` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx), which is specifically designed to handle version numbers like the ones you're trying to compare.

It provides a [`CompareTo` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5ts8tb6.aspx) that accepts another `Version` object to compare against, and returns a value indicating their relative values.